# how to get the list of undo items in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions

i'm writing a Visual Studio extension and searching for the list of history items.
i do have the `IWpfTextView`, `ITextUndoHistory`, `ITextUndoHistoryRegistry` and `ITextBufferUndoManagerProvider`.

where can i find the list of undo items?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio all of the undo types you mentioned are essentially wrappers over `IOleUndoManager`.  This is the core undo / redo type in Visual Studio.  You can use the `EnumUndoable` method on that type to view the undo units on a buffer

Comment: tnx, how do i get the IOleUndoManager?

Comment: @shemesh it should be available by using `QueryService` on the related `IVsWindowFrame` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164723.aspx